# Deploy Laravel and react in windows server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, virtual-machine

How can I deploy a Laravel API project and react js (2 separate project) build in a windows server (virtual machine from azure), and can I access the system from public IP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad. Install the web server to deploy the react project, and install both the web server and PHP to deploy the PHP project.

Comment: sorry I am a beginner in this field
Can you specify which web server you usually use for deployments

Comment: @AnanthanThampy Try nginx. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/

Comment: @AnanthanThampy Apache is also a good alternative.